# DirectCast an Object with a type as string

Tags: vb.net, casting, controls

Hi I want to set different propertyvalues of different control objects at runtime. Therefore I want to DirectCast the object by its name and its type.
But I want to set it dynamically. So I want to use the Controltype string as type for the DirectCast.

Here is an example. For sure I know it does not work with this but I already tried several approaches with e.g: DynamicCast or Gettype...
Please tell if you need further information

```
Dim Controlname As String = inhalt(0, 0, 0)
Dim ControlProperty As String = inhalt(0, 0, 1)
Dim text As String = inhalt(0, 0, 2)
Dim Controltype As String = "System.Windows.Controls.TabItem"

Dim control = DirectCast(FindName(Controlname), controltype)
Dim prop = control.[GetType]().GetProperty(ControlProperty, BindingFlags.[Public] Or BindingFlags.Instance)
prop.SetValue(control, text, Nothing)
```

Comment: There is no point in casting when you don't know the type at compile time. Why not just leave the cast away? You don't need `control` to find the type represented by `controlType`.

Comment: I have some controls like Buttons or TabItems and I want to change their values - for example TabItem.Header or Button.Content and I can already do it with this code but I want to set the type of the control dynamically. For example when its a Button I need "System.Windows.Controls.Button" or when it is a tabitem I need "System.Windows.Controls.TabItem".
So I don't want to find the controltsype but the control using a string where the controltype is set. Or maybe I understood your answer wrongly..

Comment: Yes, apparently you did. If you don't know the type of `control` at compile time, there is no point in declaring it differently than `As Object`. So I don't see why you would want to do anything like that. Why do you want to cast?

Comment: I want to cast it to use it and to set its property

Comment: Instead of storing the names of the controls, you can store references to the controls, e.g. `Dim myButtons = {Button1, Button2, Button3}`. Does that give you any ideas?

Comment: Well to clear it up a bit - I have several contorls and i want to edit their Contents or headers. Because I have a database and when I change the language the contents etc. should change. So I have a database where I link th Button names to the translations. And when I change the language I want to set the content of buttons or the headers of tabitems and so I need to cast the object to access their properties and change them, right?

But I do not know how the storing of the controls could help me with this, sorry

Comment: No, you don't need to cast just to set the property. That's what I am trying to tell you. You can just call `GetType()` on any object. Or if you don't have access to an object, use [`Type.GetType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you mean?
For me it is not clear how i can achieve what I want with the `GetType()` method..

Comment: `Dim control = FindName(Controlname)` and `control.[GetType]().GetProperty(...)`

Comment: okay - that was way too easy. thank you !:)

Comment: @LM_DMKHNGST [Walkthrough: Localizing Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3(v=vs.100).aspx) may be of interest to you.